# Perl: Looping through filehandles

Tags: perl, for-loop, file-handling, filehandle

I'm a self-taught Perler, seeking assistance from the Perl experts:

I keep getting an error saying I can't use the filehandle within a `foreach` loop, even though I'm sure to `close` it (or `undef` it, I've tried both). See the full error here: http://cl.ly/image/2b2D1T403s14

The code is available on GitHub: https://github.com/bsima/yeast-TRX

The code in question can be found in the file "script.pl" at around line 90:

```
foreach my $species (keys %Saccharomyces) {
    open(RAW,">./data/$species/$geneName/raw.csv");
        print RAW "gene,dinucleotide,position,trx.score,energy.score\n";
    undef RAW; 
    open(SMOOTH,">./data/$species/$geneName/smooth.csv");
        print SMOOTH "gene,position,trx.score,energy.score\n";
    undef SMOOTH;
}
```

Help is much appreciated! I don't know the intricacies of how Perl works with filehandles, probably because of my lack of formal training. Any comments on my overall code quality is welcome too, if someone is feeling particularly helpful.

EDIT: Found the problem. Perl cannot generate directories on the fly, so the `$species/$geneName` directory was never even being created. I added a line at the beginning of the `foreach` loop that said simply `mkdir("$species/$geneName");` and that solve the issue.

Comment: A quick look at `perldoc -f undef` lists the kinds of things that you can use it on.  Bareword filehandles are not on that list.  Take MVP's advice & use `close` & lexical filehandles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perl cannot generate directories on the fly, so the `$species/$geneName` directory was never even being created. I added a line at the beginning of the `foreach` loop that said simply `mkdir("$species/$geneName");` and that solve the issue.

Answer (score 6):

You are getting warning that is quite telling:

> Bareword RAW not allowed while "strict subs" in use

Also, `undef FILEHANDLE` is not as good as `close FILEHANDLE`.

Solution is to use normal scoped variables for file handles and close them, something like this:

```
foreach my $species (keys %Saccharomyces) {
    open my $raw, ">", "./data/$species/$geneName/raw.csv";
    print $raw "gene,dinucleotide,position,trx.score,energy.score\n";
    close $raw;
    open my $smooth, ">", "./data/$species/$geneName/smooth.csv";
    print $smooth "gene,position,trx.score,energy.score\n";
    close $smooth;
}
```

Also, you should check if `$raw` and `$smooth` were opened before trying to write to them.

Comment: I tried that. Unfortunately, I get an error saying I'm trying to print on a previously closed filehandle: [screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s1/sh/dca78b97-9670-4897-b631-0a5b84c0b9c2/ed635c1a5a87bf6fdc6d20aacca3cce9)

Comment: I thought `undef` would allow me to open a separate file and re-use `my $raw` or `my $smooth`, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: It does not make any sense, and your screenshot is *still* showing global filehandle `GENEFILE`. Code `open my $fd, ">", filename; print $fd "text"; close $fd;` cannot fail if you have permission to create `$filename` in first place. Please show your real code.